# in es6 do we need to add `return` literal, if there are conditions within function

Tags: ecmascript-6, language-features

As far as I have used es6; I come to know that in this we can omit `return` literal like

```
.then((res) => res.body } // equivalent to return res.body
```

so my question is if there are multiple conditions in the function then do we need to write return within the condition or It will do its job? ( means functional will execute without the return )

```
.then((res) => {
    if (some_codition) {
        res.send();
    } else {
        if (other_condition)
            res.status(200).json(user);
        else
            res.status(404).json(user);
    }
})
```

will above work Or do I need to add `return` as a best practice?

Comment: I would say that adding `return` is a good practice always, with the exception for functions that have only one statement. This is a matter of readability. It should be immediately obvious that the method returns something.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it will do its job*"?

Comment: Arrow functions only return anything implicitly when you use the concise body syntax (consisting of a single expression). As soon as you use a *block* (`{ … }`) for the body, it's just a normal function.

Comment: Your first code piece has bad closing brace. It will only work if you use parentheses actually.

Comment: Hey, did my answer satisfy your question? Could you accept it? If not, what would you say it's missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to manually return a value. If you don't it will return `undefined`.

Always returning value within a Promise is a good idea because allows chaining. If you return nothing (undefined) you promise-chain won't continue from that point inwards.

In this specific case it might work for you because you are calling a "side-effect" function, which is your webserver response fn.

Answer (score 0):

The difference lies in whether you have braces after the arrow or not.

```
.then(res => res.x)  // Works
.then(res => {return res.x;})  // Works
.then(res => {res.x;})  // Your function returns undefined.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.then((res) => (somecodition) ?
                        res.send()
                    :
                        res.status(200).json(user)
      )
```

try that...

Comment: I am not looking for the method alternative

Comment: if you use => {} then inside the {} you need to use return

Comment: but it works without return if there is no body in the function except return statement.